# How do I replace an excel sheet in an excel workbook with another excel sheet in r?

Tags: r

For example, I can replace the value of the second element of vector q like this:

```
q<-1:5
q[2]<-4
q
```

How do I do something similar for replacing an excel sheet in an excel workbook in r?

Comment: What package are you using to interface between Excel and R? That will determine the syntax because base R doesn't have any method for opening Excel workbooks on its own.

Comment: I'm using dplyr and openxlsx

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Looks like the easiest method would be to open the workbook, extract the sheet you're interested in to an R object, then `writeDataTable` with  x = the R object and sheet = the sheet # you'd like to replace

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do an Excel sheet replacement with the following code. First, we copy an Excel sheet. After, we delete the previous Excel sheet.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\output2.xlsx"
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\file1.xlsx"
path_Excel_File2 <- "D:\\file2.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File2)

# We replace the first sheet of the workbook xlWbk2 
xlWbk1$Worksheets(1)$Copy(after = xlWbk2$Worksheets(1))
xlWbk2$Worksheets(1)$Delete()

xlWbk2$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output) # Excel file with first sheet replaced

xlWbk1$Close()
xlWbk2$Close()
xlApp$Quit()
```